# ignore all files in subdirectory except specific file-types

Tags: git, gitignore

How do I ignore all files and directories in a specific sub-directory except for those that are or include .md files?

### My directory setup looks similar to

```
{other directories and files that should not be effected}
media\
    images\
        {other files}
        readme.md
    audio\
        {other files}
        readme.md
    video\
        {other files}
        readme.md
    {other files}
    readme.md
```

Note that nested directories may be of arbitrary depth so static exclusion/inclusion for each sub-directory isn't an option.

### Things I've tried:

```
media/*
!media/*.md
```

*Search terms used: .gitignore ignore all files in subdirectory except markdown*

The suggested duplicate question is dealing specifically with excluding all but a specific subfolder's contents. That is not what I wish. I want to ignore everything but .md files in a sub-folder and its nested directories

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by:

```
# Ignore all files and directories(recursively)
media/**

# Exclude .md files
!media/**/*.md
```

Answer (score 0):

gitignore cannot ignore already tracked files.

Try clearing your tracked files cache:

```
git rm --cached -r
```

Comment: Even if the files have yet to be staged/commited?